# Simple cURL response API

Tags: php, api, rest, soap, curl

i have been developing a URL shortener and would now like to add the API feature in. I have played around with cURL for a while and cannot get it working.

Can firstly anyone help me to give data via GET in the URL to another website, that website will then process that GET data and then can it return a result to the website that is requesting the data.

How can this work? I only need some simple code for me to then add more functions into.

Can someone give me an example in two separate pieces, one for the requesting code and one for the processing code.

Thank you so much!
Harry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can send the URL by encoding it with [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) - like:

```
GET http://yoursite.com/shorten.php?url=encoded_url
```

in your shorten.php file you will have access to `$_GET['url']` variable, which, when you decode it with [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) will get you the original url.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however, how do i send this data back? Once it has been shortened, is there some sort of return option.

Comment: you can send it in the body of the web page your service return (with simple `print()` )

Comment: Would you at all mind just righting me a simple curl request and response form, so i can just see the structure?

Comment: Don't worry all sorted, you had the final piece to the puzzle!

Answer (score 1):

You can learn how to use cURL properly with PHP in the [PHP cURL documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).  The documentation there is simple to learn and understand, so long as you have a basic understanding of HTTP.

It's up to you how you process responses from cURL.  cURL will give you the HTTP response headers and body.  If you're making an API for users to request third party sites, it's up to you how you process the responses you get from those sites.

Why do you need cURL for a URL shortener, may I ask?  The job of a URL shortener is to redirect users when they come in through links.  Requesting third party sites is not part of the job.

Comment: It's for an API, as i said in the title =)

Comment: Yes, but why do you need to use cURL in *your* API?  What will your API do, exactly?

Comment: All URL shorteners have an API, it allows other websites to have automatically shortened links. Looks at Twitter, it uses the t.co API or the Bit.ly API, anyway ive worked it out now.

Comment: Yes, but those have nothing to do with cURL requests.  An API just creates links on their sites.. cURL isn't involved.

Comment: It has everything to do with cURL, REST or SOAP requests, a website will run a function on a URL which will give the URL to the URL shortener website, the website will then shorten it, add it to their database and then return the shortened URL to be shown on the requesting website.

Comment: Yes, but it's not you who is doing the cURL request if you're serving the API.  It is the user of your API.

Comment: Yes but i at least need to write something for people who want to use the API.

Comment: Got you-- you should have made that clear in your question.  It sounds like you need to use it.  Like I said, go to the PHP cURL documentation for simple examples